# How to open a lightbox on page load if url equals using google tag manager

Tags: javascript, lightbox, google-tag-manager, featherlight.js

The title pretty much says it. I would like to show a lightbox on page load only if the url is www.example.com/#popup versus www.example.com

If this could be accomplished with google tag manager that would be grand

I've see bits and pieces of this but I'm having trouble piecing it all together.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a> 
<div id="mylightbox">This div will be opened in a lightbox</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (window.location.hash === "#popup") {
    $.featherlight("#mylightbox");                   
}
```

See https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#manual-calling-of-featherlight

**Fiddle** Shows manual lightbox open call.
http://jsfiddle.net/fm9wp96r/

Comment: Would I place all lightbox code in there? java/css/etc?

Comment: Just the Javascript, which lightbox are you using? Post your JS/HTML in the question if you can :}

Comment: I'm trying to use featherlight.

<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.2.3/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="Featherlight Styles" />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.2.3/release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<a href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a>
<div id="mylightbox">This div will be opened in a lightbox</div>