# Using Google Tag Manager to show overlay popup

Tags: javascript, popup, overlay, google-tag-manager

I tried to find a method to load an overlay popup through just Google Tag Manager. I've found a post on stackoverflow ([How to open a lightbox on page load if url equals using google tag manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923109/how-to-open-a-lightbox-on-page-load-if-url-equals-using-google-tag-manager)), but that didn't help or I didn't understood what I needed to do.

I tried Featherlight through Google tag manager. I've made a custom HTML tag and added the following: 
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script><script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.7.13/release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
$.featherlight("#mylightbox");
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a> <div id="mylightbox">This div will be opened in a lightbox</div>`

But that didn't popup anything. Could someone help me out. I don't have much experience in javascript.